# MongoDB simultaneous read in java

Tags: java, mongodb

Can I read data simultaneously from different collections in MongoDB? Using Threading in java. I have those collections stored in the same database in mongodb. Plz help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the MongoDB Java driver supports multi-threaded access to the mongod server. [Java Driver Concurrency](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Driver+Concurrency) describes concurrency considerations with the driver.

Comment: Multi-threading on the driver side has very little to do with MongoDB read concurrency. Even a single thread driver could do concurrent reads from different collections (on the MongoDB level). I'm not argueing that there's no performance difference but it's not a requirement since Java supports non-blocking I/O.